# glVertexAttribPointer normalization

Tags: opengl, 3d

glVertexAttribPointer(index,  size,  type, normalized, stride,  pointer);

If I use type=GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and normalized=GL_TRUE

how is it normalized?
would the data be divided by 256 for normalization? or?
This would mean there is no way to have a normalized value of '1.0f'..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the manual,

> If set to GL_TRUE, normalized indicates that values stored in an integer format are to be mapped to the range [-1,1] (for signed values) or [0,1] (for unsigned values) when they are accessed and converted to floating point.

I take that to mean that, with an unsigned 8 bit type, 0 would map to 0.0f and 255 would map to 1.0f.

Comment: So that means it is divided by 255?

Comment: Right, unsigned byte has range of 0 - 255. So if you passed 0xFF (which is equal to 255), you'd get 1.0f.

Comment: ... Did you ever play the original Zelda? The maximum amount of rubies you could hold was 255, not 256 ;)

Comment: I know that unsigned bytes only go to 255.. I was just wondering because it seemed logic for the GPU to divide by a power-of-two

Comment: I was wondering something similar. There may be an efficient conversion from uint_8 to float that doesn't do much more than shifting bits around, but I'm not the one to ask... Someone who knows more about FPU's might chime in?